# Indian states duplicate entries after magento Upgrade

Tags: magento2

I had manually inserted Indian states in Magento 2.2.2. I have upgraded to 2.2.6 and I am seeing duplicate entries.

Could this be because 2.2.6 came with Indian states adding to the existing entries and resulting in duplicate?

How can I get rid of this duplicate entries?
Also when I run below sql statement I see only one entry and here is  the screenshot.

> SELECT * FROM `directory_country_region` WHERE country_id='IN';

But when I run

> SELECT * FROM `directory_country_region` WHERE default_name='Delhi';

it shows two entries.

[image: Indian states duplicate entries]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your store doesn't have many customer which used `region_id` in their address then you can run default `sql_statement` for retriving duplicate data & delete it.

The following statement deletes duplicate rows and keeps the highest id.

```
DELETE t1 FROM `directory_country_region` t1 INNER JOIN `directory_country_region` t2 WHERE t1.region_id < t2.region_id AND t1.default_name = t2.default_name
```

If you want to deletes duplicate rows and keeps the lowest id.

```
DELETE t1 FROM `directory_country_region` t1 INNER JOIN `directory_country_region` t2 WHERE t1.region_id > t2.region_id AND t1.default_name = t2.default_name
```

Else you have to create script for checking which region_id is being used in customer address and delete other duplicate entry of it.

Hope this will be helpful!.

Comment: You can follow this tutorial for multiple methods http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-delete-duplicate-rows/

Comment: I don't have customers at the moment. Is it safe to execute the above script Or can i delete one by one from PHPmyAdmin? which one would be safer?

Comment: You can execute this script from phpmyadmin

Comment: Yes I understand that. What about deleting one by one from PHPmyadmin without query?

Comment: @Haya it will take time nothing else if system give you automated script then you should use it for save time and in proper way to get it done without human errors.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer so for other users it will be helpful.

Comment: I have duplicate entries in directory_country_region_name also

Comment: I have total 72 records at the end of both tables directory_country_region_name and directory_country_region. Should I delete first 32 or last 32?

Comment: This solution is not checking for country match, it is possible to have same region names in different countries which will delete them. AFAIK Jura is the only region available in FR and CH